# How to port the Cobalt disk cache function on my board?

Tags: cobalt

I am porting cobalt on my board with version 9 now.
When I improve the speed which open the webpage, I want to use the disk cache function. I find it was  supported in verion 2.8885(https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/9e5b587d977d754145466cb318e3e9199cad50e1), but remove in version 7.19130 (https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/c2b4089af4280a65cc5e5818847e3a9a8662c215). It seems that I can carry the files which in version 2.8885 under the src/net/disk_cache/  into my project and change some initial files to get my point. But the way to enable disk cache functions is right? and the reason that why remove this functions after version 7.19130

Comment: Note that the best way to reduce a startup latency is to preload a web app. Preloading is available in Cobalt 11.

Comment: thanks for your help, and I will try it when cobalt 11 release.

Comment: Upvote my comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source files were removed because they weren't used. They are still not used, so bringing them back, sadly, will not help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Will cobalt plan to support disk cache functions in the future?   I find net/disk_cache/disk_cache.h doesn`t be remove now with mock implement for unit test.  If it will not support int the future, maybe I would think other ways to improve the speed.

Comment: We may, but there are no concrete plans at this point. It's possibly less worthwhile than investing in smarter use of memory, like an encoded image in-memory cache.